# How can i download all types of file in python with request library

Tags: python, request

I am building the crawler in python and i have the list of `href` from the page.

Now i have the list of file extensions to download like

`list = ['zip','rar','pdf','mp3']`

How can i save the files from that url to local directory using python

EDIT:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.example.com/downlaod"

site = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = site.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

list_urls = soup.find_all('a')

print list_urls[6]
```

Comment: It would really help if you showed us the code you've already built that gets the initial page and pulls the `href`s out of it…

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to name a list `list`. That's the name of the `list` type and constructor function, which you can't use anymore if you give a variable the same name.

Comment: Why did you ask about `requests` and then show sample code with `urllib2`? Meanwhile… what part are you stuck on? What does `list_urls[6]` print out when you print it? What do you want to do with it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by your posted example:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.example.com/downlaod"

site = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = site.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

list_urls = soup.find_all('a')

print list_urls[6]
```

So, the URL you want to fetch next is presumably `list_urls[6]['href']`.

The first trick is that this might be a relative URL rather than absolute. So:

```
newurl = list_urls[6]['href']
absurl = urlparse.urljoin(site.url, newurl)
```

Also, you want to only fetch the file if it has the right extension, so:

```
if not absurl.endswith(extensions):
    return # or break or whatever
```

But once you've decided what URL you want to download, it's no harder than your initial fetch:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(absurl)
html = page.read()
path = urlparse.urlparse(absurl).path
name = os.path.basename(path)
with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

That's mostly it.

There are a few things you might want to add, but if so, you have to add them all manually. For example:

- Look for a Content-disposition header with a suggested filename to use in place of the URL's basename.
- `copyfile` from `page` to `f` instead of `read`ing the whole thing into memory and then `write`ing it out.
- Deal with existing files with the same name.
- …

But that's the basics.

Comment: thanks buddy , i will go from there. when u say from `r` to `f` what does it mean. so basically all files are contents which we can write. does not matter if its mp3 or pdf or zip. i was thinking only text files can be read and written

Comment: Sorry, I used `f` as the local file opened by `open` and `r` as the result of `urlopen` (because that's what the docs use when they're not using `f`)… but I should have realized that my own code above called it `page` rather than `r`. I'll edit it, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Anyway, yes, binary files are still just files. (Except that on Windows, you may have to be careful to use `'wb'` instead of `'w'` so Python doesn't try to "fix text newlines" in files that aren't actually text. If you switch to Python 3.x, the differences between binary and text make a lot more sense, but I don't want to confuse you with that as long as you're using 2.x.) And the whole point of `urllib2` is that it lets you treat web pages just like files. So, really, this is just copying from one file to another.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python requests library as you have asked in question : http://www.python-requests.org

You can save file from url like this :

```
import requests

url='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJdh.jpg'

data=requests.get(url).content

filename="image.jpg"

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution using urllib3

```
import os
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse 
url = "https://path/site"
site = urllib3.PoolManager()
html = site.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.data, "lxml")
list_urls = soup.find_all('a')
```

and then a recursive function to get all the files

```
def recursive_function(list_urls)
    newurl = list_urls[0]['href']
    absurl = url+newurl
    list_urls.pop(0)
    if absurl.endswith(extensions): # verify if contains the targeted extensions
        page = urllib3.PoolManager()
        html = site.request('GET', absurl)
        name = os.path.basename(absurl)
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(html.data)
    return recursive_function(list_urls)
```